# Android dev in Intellij,How to clean PNG cache only?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

Is there anyway to clean cache(like png),as we do in eclipse -->clean project.
I knew it can do file-->invalidate caches,but in this way, the local history will be cleaned also. I just clean PNG caches,because sometimes we modified some png,then save as the same name, when we run programe again,the png will still use the cache file.It puzzle me for a long time.Anyone could help me? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Build -> Rebuild Project`.